# Router connection falling

Tags: networking, router, internet-connection

I am encoutering a problem with a Zyxel Prestige 650HW router. Almost every night the internet connection falls and when in the morning I power it off and on again the connection is re-established.

The configuration is as follows:

```
WAN Information:
    Mode: Routing
    Encapsulation: PPPoE
    Multiplexing: LLC
    VPI/VCI: 8/35
    Service Name : otenet
User Name : ***********
Password : ********
IP Address : Obtain an IP Address Automatically
Network Address Translation: SUA Only
Connection: Nailed-Up Connection

LAN Information:
    IP Address: 10.100.1.251
    IP Mask: 255.255.255.0
    DHCP: ON
    Client IP Pool Starting Address: 192.***.**.**
    Size of Client IP Pool: 32
```

Comment: That config doesn’t show us ADSL settings like your SNR percentage and ratios, can you provide them maybe?

Comment: @Ben Good point! Inside the web configuration console of the router, there's a menu "Maintenance" with a sub menu entry called "Diagnostics". This includes "General" and "DSL Line". Regarding the later, it has the following button/actions to perform: ATM loopback test, ATM status, Upstream/Downstream noise margin, Reset ADSL line. Would any of those be useful in this case? "General" has only a ping function and a System Reset button.

Comment: You can generate ADSL stats that way and provide them to your ISP, normally noise margins cause a lot of drop-outs on ADSL lines. Do you know what your SNR percentage is now?